# Is the sequence of function $\frac{\sin nx}{\pi x}$ convergent to $\delta(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I have no doubt that the integral of the function from negative infinity to positive infinity is 1. But I don't think $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin nx}{\pi x} \rightarrow 0 $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $ given $x\ne 0$, which doesn't fit the definition of $\delta(x)$. Do you agree with that?

Comment: It is senseless to say a sequence of functions converges to "$\delta(x)$". What you might be thinking is that for sufficiently nice $f(x)$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)f_n(x)dx=f(0)$$

Comment: Yes, you're right. My statement is not that rigid

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I think it does make sense, you just have to be aware that everything is in the bigger space of distributions. That's exactly what you describe. The thing is that convergence pointwise isn't convergence in the sense of distributions.

Comment: You can find online the article/script of Carl Offner: "A little harmonic analysis", where summation methods, Dirichlet and Poisson kernels and the inverse of the Fourier transform are discussed in a very readable format. -- What Pedro wrote is the distributional interpretation of the limit, your point about pointwise convergence is also true. That is why one demands that approximations of the delta distributions be positive functions. Like $e^{-n\,|x|}$ or $\frac{n}{n^2+x^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your definition of the Dirac delta. The mathematically sound definition is that it is a distribution defined by its application to test functions $φ\in C_0^\infty(\Bbb R)$ as
$$
δ(φ)=\langle δ,φ\rangle=φ(0)
$$
Now the $f_n$ are locally integrable functions and thus related to a regular distribution 
\begin{align}
T_{f_n}(φ)&=\int_{\Bbb R}f_n(x) φ(x)\,dx=\langle f_n,φ\rangle_{L^2}
\\
&=\langle \hat f_n,\hat φ\rangle_{L^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat φ(ω)\cdot 1\,dω
\end{align}
By the dominated convergence theorem, $T_{f_n}(φ)$ converges to
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-∞}^{∞}\hat φ(ω)\cdot 1\,dω=φ(0)
$$
that is, $T_{f_n}\to δ$ as a distribution.

---

What you had in mind by trying to prove pointwise convergence is the idea of an approximate identity (of convolution) or a delta-approximating sequence. For such a sequence $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ one demands, for the reasons obvious in the sequence of Dirichlet kernels, that

- $f_n(x)\ge 0$, the functions are non-negative,
- $\int_{\Bbb R}f_n(x)\,dx=1$ and
- $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\to 0$ for $x\ne 0$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{\Bbb R}f_n(x)φ(x)\,dx-φ(0)\right|
&\le\int_{\Bbb R}|f_n(x)|\,|φ(x)-φ(0)|\,dx
\\
&\le \int_{\Bbb R}|f_n(x)|\,dx\cdot\sup_{x\in[-a,a]}|φ(x)-φ(0)|+\int_{|x|\ge a} |f_n(x)|\,|φ(x)-φ(0)|\,dx
\end{align}
$$
The first term is controlled by the continuity of $φ$, the second by dominated convergence and the pointwise convergence of the $f_n$.

---

Examples of delta-approximating sequences are

- $\frac{n}2\,e^{-n\,|x|}$
- $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}\,e^{-n\,x^2}$
- $\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$
- $C\cdot \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{nx^2}$ for some constant $C$,...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sin\pars{nx} \over \pi x}}
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{%
{n \over \pi}\bracks{\sin\pars{nx} \over nx}}
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{n \over \pi}\pars{\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic knx}\,\dd k}}
\\[5mm] & =\lim_{n \to \infty}
\int_{-n}^{n}\expo{\ic kx}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic kx}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}
=\color{#00f}{\large\delta\pars{x}}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain the second step to the integral, and its transformation? thanks