# Showing some sequence of function is delta converging.

Tags: convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Show that 
$$f_n(x) = \frac{\sin nx}{\pi x}$$
converges to $\delta$ in the sense of distribution. I know the same question have been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701187/is-the-sequence-of-function-frac-sin-nx-pi-x-convergent-to-deltax). But I found some hint from Arfken Mathematical Methods for physicists which is

> Show that 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\frac{\sin nx}{\pi x}dx=0$$
>   Assume that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$ and vanishes as $x → ±∞$.
>
> Hint. Replace $x$ by $y/n$ and take $\lim\ n → ∞$ before integrating.

with this hint I found the following solution(simple to grasp) 
[image]
from [this](http://mathhelpboards.com/calculus-10/show-948-n-sin-nx-pi-x-delta-distribution-14711.html#post69588) site. Everything in the above solution is a pretty much convincing to me except while substitution the denominator should be $\pi y/n$. But having that "$n$" the limit become "ugly" and the result would be different. So, how can we show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\frac{\sin nx}{\pi x}dx=0$ using the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = nx$, then $x = y/n$ and $dx = dy/n$, hence
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\frac{\sin nx}{\pi x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y/n)\frac{\sin y}{\pi (y/n)}d(y/n)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y/n)\frac{\sin y}{\pi y}dy,$$
which allows you to pass to the limit.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Exactly, I didn't notice the $dy$. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify why you are then allowed to pass the limit? What convergence theorem is being used?